# Rails Select first Radio button in list and maintain value after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

I have the following radio_button_tag group and I want the first one to be selected and when I submit a form I want to maintain the selected value. any help would be really appreciated.

```
<% [ 'plain', 'desert', 'green', 'corporate', 'funky' ].each do |value, name| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :ed_type, (name || value) %>
            <%= label_tag :"ed_type_#{(name || value)}", value.humanize %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% [ 'plain', 'desert', 'green', 'corporate', 'funky' ].each_with_index do |value, index| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :ed_type, value, ( params[:ed_type] ? (params[:ed_type]==value) : (index==0) ) %>
            <%= label_tag value %>
<% end %>
```

My code ignores the name|value part. Am sure, you can add it by yourself.

When the form is loaded (GET request), the params[:ed_type] will be nil. So, the second condition will be evaluated and so the index==0 (the first) element will be selected.

When the form is submitted and rendered again, the params[:ed_type] will not be nil. So, the first condition is always evaluated and turns true for the appropriate radio-button.

Comment: That's brilliant, that is what I wanted, only one thing you forgot to add ")" at the end.  <%= radio_button_tag :ed_type, value, ((params[:ed_type] ? (params[:ed_type]==value) : (index==0))) %>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <%= radio_button_tag :ed_type, (name || value), (name == 'plain' || value == 'plain') %>
```

Comment: Thanks Ace Dimasuhid for your answer :-)